# F5 Big-IP VE incorrect load balancer operation

Tags: load-balancer, f5

I have F5 Big-IP VE version 13.1.1

LTM configuration:

- 3 nodes
- pool with LB Method Round Robin
- Virtual Server

LB (Round Robin) switches the node when the web page requests after 15 seconds. If it is requested more often (for example, once per second), then the node does not switch.

```
  > curl Virtual Server
  StatusCode        : 200
  StatusDescription : OK
  Content           : <!DOCTYPE html>
                      <html>
                      <body>

                      <h1>This is BIGIP Node1</h1>

                      </body>
                      </html>

  RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    ....
```

Immediately try it again

```
> curl Virtual Server
  StatusCode        : 200
  StatusDescription : OK
  Content           : <!DOCTYPE html>
                      <html>
                      <body>

                      <h1>This is BIGIP Node1</h1>

                      </body>
                      </html>

  RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    ....
```

After 15 seconds

```
> curl Virtual Server
  StatusCode        : 200
  StatusDescription : OK
  Content           : <!DOCTYPE html>
                      <html>
                      <body>

                      <h1>This is BIGIP Node3</h1>

                      </body>
                      </html>

  RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    ....
```

Why does F5 Big-IP not switch nodes with every request?

Comment: Please include the configuration. Most likely it's due to the persistence profile you configured (cookie or source IP address, most likely).

Comment: I do not have a permanent profile, irules or policies. This is a clean installation, I add 3 nodes, a pool and a virtual server.

Comment: Those are all not relevant for load balancing methods, it's a property of the virtual server. You can check it with `show ltm virtual <VIPNAME>` in tmsh.

Comment: I fixed it.
Enable HTTP profile - http and OneConnect Profile - oneconnect. Now, it's working correct.